# Why does this negative slice return an empty list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
nums=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23]
nums[slice(5,0,-1)]
```

returns `[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]`

I would like to slice the list backwards and include the `0` element. However

```
nums[slice(5,-1,-1)]
```

returns `[]`

Comment: If the second argument to your slice is negative, it refers to the character from the end of the `list`. So you're effectively saying, from index `5` to the last index, step negative `1`.

Comment: BTW, slices are usually written using `:` notation: `nums[5:0:-1]`

Comment: Leave out the ending number: `nums[5::-1]`

Comment: Or, if you insist on using `slice`, `nums[slice(5,None,-1)]`.

Comment: Thanks to @Barmar and @Axe319. `slice(5,None,-1)` is what I was looking for.